# Populate Nodes in TreeView based on Data stored in SQL Server

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a particular project in vb.net. In this Scenario I have some values stored in SQL server database. I want to populate tree view based on values in database. e.g.

```vb
Private Sub Populate_Tree()
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim str_Sql As String
        If cls_GeneralVariables.Group_Name = "Data Entry Operators" Then
            str_Sql = " EXEC sp_GeneratorFueling_PopulateTree_Get  " & cls_GeneralVariables.LoginEmployeeId
        Else
            str_Sql = " EXEC sp_GeneratorFueling_PopulateTree_Get 0 "
        End If
        dt = cls_GeneralFunction.Get_DataTable(str_Sql, cls_GeneralVariables.Sql_Connection)
        bln_Populate = False
        If tv_SurveyDate.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes.Clear()
        End If
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim iLoop As Integer
            Dim pNode, pNode_Value, pNode1 As Integer
            Dim pYear As String = Nothing

            For iLoop = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

                With dt.Rows(iLoop)
                    If pYear <> .Item("Year") Then
                        '--- Add New Year Node
                        pYear = .Item("Year")
                        tv_SurveyDate.Nodes.Add(.Item("Year"))
                        If iLoop > 0 Then
                            pNode = pNode + 1
                        End If
                        ''--- Add Child Nodes
                        If pNode_Value <> .Item("MONTH") Then
                            pNode_Value = .Item("MONTH")
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("MonthTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("MONTH")
                            'tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")
                            '--- Flush pNode1 

                            pNode1 = 0

                            ''--- Add 2nd Child Nodes
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("FuelingTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("FuelingID")
                            ''tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")
                        Else
                            '    ''--- Add 2nd Child Nodes

                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("FuelingTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("FuelingID")
                            '    'tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")
                        End If
                        tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode = tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1)
                        If .Item("Color") = "White" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.White
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Yellow" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Orange" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Orange
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LimeGreen" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LightGreen" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LightPink" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Aqua" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Aqua
                        End If
                    Else




                        ''--- Add Child Nodes
                        If pNode_Value <> .Item("MONTH") Then
                            pNode_Value = .Item("MONTH")
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("MonthTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("MONTH")
                            'tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")
                            '--- Add 2nd Child Nodes

                            If iLoop > 0 Then
                                pNode1 = pNode1 + 1
                            End If

                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("FuelingTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("FuelingID")
                            ' tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")

                        Else

                            '    '--- Add 2nd Child Nodes
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Add(Format(.Item("FuelingTitle")))
                            tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).Tag = .Item("FuelingID")
                            '    'tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1).ToolTipText = .Item("MONTH")
                        End If
                        tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode = tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes(tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(pNode).Nodes(pNode1).Nodes.Count - 1)
                        If .Item("Color") = "White" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.White
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Yellow" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Orange" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Orange
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LimeGreen" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LightGreen" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "LightPink" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                        ElseIf .Item("Color") = "Aqua" Then
                            tv_SurveyDate.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Aqua
                        End If
                    End If

                End With
            Next
            bln_Populate = True
            'tv_SurveyDate.Nodes(0).Expand()
            tv_SurveyDate.CollapseAll()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

An Exception is displayed "Specified Arguments was out of range of valid values. Parameter Name: Index"

Comment: This site provides a preview of your question for a reason. Please use it and don't submit if your formatting is a mess. If you don't know how to format properly, please spend some time in the Help Center and learn.

Comment: As for the issue, where does the exception get thrown? What was the index? What was the valid range? You need to do appropriate debugging and testing to isolate the issue first and try to solve it for yourself rather than just drop everything here for us to work out at the first sign of trouble. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly, posting ONLY the relevant code.

Comment: I agree with the above comments re amount of code. But a quick look says it's database related, where the index parameter in the stored procedure is receiving an invalid value. Out of range means that you are passing in a number which is greater (or less than) it is expecting. Either change the value type to manage a bigger range, or add a check before the sp is called.